# summing string and integers in list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a blackjack code in python 2.7 and can't figure out how to sum my c1 and c2 once an output is given. This is what I have so far:

```
def blackjackTips(c1,c2):
    print "Welcome to Blackjack!"
    print "Your cards are", name[c1-1],"&",name[c2-1]
    total= sum ([c1]+[c2])
    print "Your card total is",total
name = ('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K')
value = (11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)
```

output:

```
>>> blackjackTips(11,6)
Welcome to Blackjack!
Your cards are J & 6
Your card total is 17
```

*The current syntax return the wrong sum is being calculated. The sum should be 16.

Could someone please provide guidance?

Thank you

Comment: You want 11+6 to equal 16?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, in blackjack, all the cards from `10` upward are counted to as `10` points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
total = value[c1-1]+value[c2-1]
```